# WPF Combobox how to populate with list

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm building a budget tracking app for myself as I teach myself to program and I want to have categories of things I spend my money on. I have a `combobox` which I would like to be populated by the contents of a List which hold the categories. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply assign a collection of items to the `ItemsSource` property:

```
comboBox.ItemsSource = new List<string> { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
```

See the Remarks for the [ItemsControl.ItemsSource Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource?view=netframework-4.7.2) on MS Docs:

> Content Model: This property may be used to add items to an ItemsControl.
>
> A common scenario is to use an ItemsControl such as a ListBox, ListView, or TreeView to display a data collection, or to bind an ItemsControl to a collection object. To bind an ItemsControl to a collection object, use the ItemsSource property. Note that the ItemsSource property supports OneWay binding by default.
>
> When the ItemsSource property is set, the Items collection is made read-only and fixed-size.

---

To my understanding, the `Items` property mainly exists as a default collection where items are added when you assign them directly in XAML. ItemsControls are attributed with

```
[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Items")]
```

to support XAML like this:

```
<ComboBox>
    <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Item 3</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

To populate a combobox with contents of a list one needs to add each item of that list into `items` of the combobox.

A minimal example, assuming you have a `comboBox1` defined:

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string> { "item1", "item2", "item3" };
        myList.ForEach(x => { comboBox1.Items.Add(x); });
```